# Find all the points satisfying the Fritz John conditions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the problem 
$$\min \>x^2+y^2 $$
$$s.t.\> x^2-(y-1)^3=0$$

1. Find all the points satisfying the Fritz John conditions

   ## Solution

The FJ conditions are
$$2x+\mu_1 2x=0$$
$$2y-\mu_1 3(y-1)^2=0$$
But I am stuck from here

2. One may be tempted to solve the optimization problem by substituting $ x^ 2 = (y − 1) ^3$ in the objective, thereby reducing it to the un-
   constrained problem $\min \> y^ 2 + (y − 1)^ 3$ . But something is wrong with this approach. What is it and how can it be corrected?

Comment: The Fritz John conditions allow for a zero multiplier on the cost, which you do not have above.

Comment: That actually just confused me. So are there FT conditions @copper.hat

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: I didn't understand your first comment @copper.hat

Comment: I'll add an answer to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1:

The problem has the form $\min \{ f(x) | h(x) = 0 \}$. (I am using $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ here.)

It helps to plot the set of $x$ satisfying $h(x) = 0$.
[image]

A look at the picture will convince you that the solution is $(0,1)$.

The Fritz John conditions are necessary conditions and always hold at an extremum. In this case, the Fritz John conditions give: $h(x) = 0$ and
$\lambda_0 \nabla f(x) + \nu \nabla h(x) = 0$, with $\lambda_0 \ge 0$ and
$(\lambda_0, \nu) \neq 0$. (Note the presence of the $\lambda_0$, which is
different from the Lagrange conditions.)

The points that satisfy the Fritz John conditions are the $((x_1,x_2), \lambda_0, \nu)$ that satisfy the above conditions. 
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1^2 - (x_2-1)^3 &=& 0 \\
\lambda_0 \binom{x_1}{x_2} + \nu \binom{2x_1}{-3(x_2-1)^2} &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
We solve this by case analysis.

Suppose $x_1 \neq 0$. Then the top line of the gradient equation gives $\lambda_0 = - 2 \nu$ and hence both are non zero.
Substituting for $\lambda_0$ and dividing through by $-\nu$ gives 
$2 x_2 + 3(x_2-1)^2 = 0$. This quadratic has no real solutions.

Hence we must have $x_1=0$, then the constraint gives $x_2 = 1$, and the gradient condition gives $\lambda_0 = 0$, hence the Fritz John points are
$((0,1),0, \nu)$, with $\nu \neq 0$.

Note that the multiplier on $\nabla f(x)$ is zero.

Part 2:

Note that if $h(x) = 0$, we **must** have $x_2 \ge 1$. This is a subtle
implicit constraint that 'disappears' if we just substitute $(x_2-1)^3$,
for $x_1^2$. If we eliminate $x_1$ by substituting $x_1^2 = (x_2-1)^3$, we must also ensure that $x_2 \ge 1$.
If we do not add the latter constraint, then it should be clear that the
cost $y^2+(y-1)^3$ is unbounded below.

As an aside, the 'problem' here is that the relation $x_1^2 = (x_2-1)^3$ is
not a function, despite the suggestive form in which it is written. If the
constraint was of the form $h(x) = x_1-g(x_2)$, then we could safely
substitute $x_1$ by $g(x_2)$.